# Adding Objects in UIScrollView disturbs x and y position

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, interface-builder

This procedure kills so much of my time and it is really annoying me.

I am working in Interface Builder.

My objects ( `UIButton` , `UILabels` , `UIImageViews` etc. ) are added in a `UIView`. I added a `UIScrollView` when I drag them in a `UIScrollView`, the position (x and y) is disturbed.

And I have to set them again - each control. 
I am looking for an easier solution. As in that i dont have to set 'x' & 'y' for each control whenever i drag them into UIScrollView.

Taimur

Comment: Are you dragging it directly in the xib or dragging it under objects(on left side of the xib).

Comment: Apparently this is a result of 'Auto-Layout'. What are your thoughts?

Comment: @jipp, I drag the UIScroll in the left window pane. And then drag objects into the scrollview , and drag the objects and allign little to the right to be placed under the scrollview instead of having them in the same degree under UIView. Soon the object is added in the scrollview .. The x & y position is disturbed.
The size of UIScrollView is exactly the same of a UIView.
It takes lot of donkey work to set the position again :(

Comment: @Kanan Vora , I dont think so as I have disabled the 'Auto-layout'.